# Calculating elapsed time between samples in R

Tags: r, datetime

I have a very large database and I need to calculate Elapsed time between samples and put results into another column so that I can later do duration caculations...

I have been able to mostly do this but my results aren't quite right...

```
    station$datetime<-as.POSIXct(paste(station$ï..SAMPLE_DATE,station$SampleTime), format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

    storder<-station[order(station$datetime),]  

    storder$timeel <- storder$datetime - storder$datetime[1]
```

This code works to combine and format my datetime and put in order and it does give me results of elapsed time... sorta....

```
> head(storder$datetime)
[1] "2005-06-01 09:00:01 EDT" "2005-06-01 09:15:01 EDT" "2005-06-01 09:30:01 EDT" "2005-06-01 09:45:01 EDT"
[5] "2005-06-01 10:00:01 EDT" "2005-06-01 10:15:01 EDT"
> head(storder$timeel)
Time differences in secs
[1]    0  900 1800 2700 3600 4500
```

SO my question is....  How do I get it to not be cumulative?

What I need is more along the line of 0  900  900  901  900  903 ect.... (and eventually I'll convert to minutes)

I've been looking but I'm sure I've missed something simple... again...

Comment: The `diff` function may be what you're looking for. See `?diff`

Comment: storder$timeel <- c(0, storder$datetime[-1] -storder$datetime[-nrow(storder)] )

Comment: Diff!  I knew I was overlooking something simple.  Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `diff` as Frank pointed out. To change the unit to minutes use:

```
a<-diff(storder$datetime)
units(a) <- "mins"
```